# Как развернуть массив по этому адресу "http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json" и вывести каждый элемент отдельно? У меня возвращается всё одним массивом

Tags: javascript, html, angular

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private dataUrl: string = "http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addData() {
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
  }
}
```

data.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-server',
  templateUrl: './data-server.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-server.component.scss']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

  titleBlock = "Data from the server:"
  titleData!: Object

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAddData()
  }

  getAddData() {
    this.dataService.addData().subscribe(data => {
      this.titleData = data
      console.log(this.titleData)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

data.component.html

```
<div>

  <h1>
    {{ titleBlock }}
  </h1>

  <ul>
    <li>
      {{ titleData | json  }}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
 <div>
    
      <h1>
        {{ titleBlock }}
      </h1>
    
      <ul *ngIf="titleData">
        <li *ngFor="let item of titleData.data">
          {{ item  }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    
</div>
```

Comment: ```*ngFor="let item of titleData.data"``` Пишет что нельзя перебирать titleData